# Speed up mysql table query

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have the following mysql table

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_info` (
  `auto_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `apply_dt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority_opt` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_apl_by` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_upd_by` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_upd_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `agent` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `second_agent` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `follow_up` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `funding_dt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `amt_granted` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `cred_review_fee_amt` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `cred_review_fee_dt_paid` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `cred_estab_fee_amt` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `cred_estab_fee_dt_paid` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `liq_fee_amt` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `liq_fee_dt_paid` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `miscel_fee_amt` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `miscel_fee_dt_paid` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `df_cnslt_fee_amt` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `df_cnslt_fee_date_paid` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `cred_repair_fee_amt` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `cred_repair_fee_dt_paid` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `lead_src` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `bst_time_to_call` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_psn2` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_fl_nm` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_ph1` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_ph2` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_eml1` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_eml2` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_amt_req` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_cmt` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `p_fr_nm` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_mi_nm` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT '',
  `p_la_nm` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_hm_ph` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_hm_addr` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_ye_addr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_city` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_state` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_zip` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_ss` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_is_us` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_mam_maiden_nm` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_drv_lic` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_unq_id` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_hv_af` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_wh_af` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_hv_dod` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_wh_dod` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_bnk_nm` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_stg` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_leg_nm` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_ent_typ` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_ind_typ` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_fed_tax_id` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_ph` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_fax` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_addr` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT '',
  `b_city` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_state` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_zip` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_ye_busi` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `b_empl` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_reg_state` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_wb_site` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_bnk_nm` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_acpt_cred_card` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_hv_cred_card` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_seeking` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_hv_not_show_cred_card` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_wht_bnk_issu_thm` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_hv_401k_ira` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_how_much` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_cred_premis` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_cred_usr` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_cred_pwd` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_ph1` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_ph2` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_eml` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `manager` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_relation` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_ss` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_cred_usr` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_cred_pwd` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_new_buss` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_hm_addr` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_city` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_state` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `remarks` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `p_psn3` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_ph1` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_ph2` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_relation` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_ss` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_eml` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_cred_usr` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_cred_pwd` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_hm_addr` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_city` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_state` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_cred_usr` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_cred_pwd` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_facs_no` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_eml` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_acc` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_acc_ph` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_own_lease` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_type` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_addition_addr` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_landlord` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_landlord_ph` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_landlord_fr` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_landlord_to` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_landlord_month_pmt` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_landlord_renew_opt` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_landlord_renew_ye` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_landlord_payment` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_landlord_approx` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_cash` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_amex` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_vs_mc` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_other` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_is_season` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_month_season_begin` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_month_season_to` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_opportunity_yes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_zip` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_zip` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `drip` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_action_day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `drip_start_dt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `opt_yes_no` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `opportunity` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sms_log_agent` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_log_agent` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail_log_agent` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `quali_guide_result` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `quali2_guide_result` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_quali_guide_result` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_quali2_guide_result` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_quali_guide_result` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_quali2_guide_result` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `quali_result` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `rev_total_bal` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `rev_total_limit` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `rev_total_ups` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `rev_total_downs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `rev_fund_needed` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_rev_total_bal` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_rev_total_limit` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_rev_total_ups` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_rev_total_downs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_rev_fund_needed` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_rev_total_bal` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_rev_total_limit` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_rev_total_ups` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_rev_total_downs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_rev_fund_needed` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `keepaneye` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_agency` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_agency` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_agency` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor_priority_opt` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cur_credit_report1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cur_credit_report2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cur_credit_report3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quali_range` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `quali_cond` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `quali_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `quali_state` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_quali_range` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_quali_cond` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_quali_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_quali_state` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_quali_range` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_quali_cond` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_quali_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_quali_state` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `quali_range_value` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_quali_range_value` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3_quali_range_value` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_quali_range_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_quali_cond` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_quali_range` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`auto_id`),
  KEY `is_opportunity_yes` (`is_opportunity_yes`) USING HASH,
  KEY `funding_dt` (`funding_dt`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `priority_opt` (`priority_opt`) USING HASH,
  KEY `follow_priority` (`priority_opt`,`follow_up`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `funding_priority` (`priority_opt`,`funding_dt`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `p_ph1` (`p_ph1`) USING HASH,
  KEY `p_ph2` (`p_ph2`) USING HASH,
  KEY `p_eml1` (`p_eml1`) USING HASH,
  KEY `follow_up` (`follow_up`) USING HASH,
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`) USING HASH,
  KEY `auto_id` (`auto_id`),
  KEY `p2_ph1` (`p2_ph1`) USING HASH,
  KEY `p3_ph1` (`p3_ph1`) USING HASH,
  KEY `p_eml2` (`p_eml2`) USING HASH,
  KEY `p_fl_nm` (`p_fl_nm`) USING HASH,
  KEY `p2_ph2` (`p2_ph2`) USING HASH,
  KEY `p3_ph2` (`p3_ph2`) USING HASH,
  KEY `p2_eml` (`p2_eml`) USING HASH,
  KEY `p3_eml` (`p3_eml`) USING HASH,
  KEY `credit_repair` (`opt_yes_no`) USING HASH,
  KEY `sms_log_agent` (`sms_log_agent`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `call_log_agent` (`call_log_agent`) USING HASH,
  KEY `mail_log_agent` (`mail_log_agent`) USING HASH,
  KEY `quali_result` (`quali_result`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `opportunity` (`opportunity`) USING HASH,
  KEY `lead_src` (`lead_src`) USING HASH,
  KEY `cust_upd_dt` (`cust_upd_dt`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `apply_dt` (`apply_dt`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `agent` (`agent`) USING HASH,
  KEY `keepaneye` (`keepaneye`) USING HASH,
  KEY `second_agent` (`second_agent`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `max_quali_range_value` (`max_quali_range_value`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1567531 ;
```

I need improve speed of query like

```
Select * from customer_info
```

want to know how we can apply techniques to improve speed by using any method But its third party tool and we have to care about our running application as well.

Comment: 1. Never use the dreaded 'SELECT *'. Always name the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: You are right, basically I have to improve thrid-party application performance. How I can change whole application where they have used this command anywhere.

Comment: Also, any time you see enumerated column names, you can be sure that there's room for optimization through improved schema design.

Comment: Find and replace?

Comment: so you means I would replace select * with all above columns. Please answer you solution

Comment: no improvement by using: SELECT `auto_id`, `customer_id`, `apply_dt`, `priority_opt`, `cust_apl_by`, `cust_upd_by`, `cust_upd_dt`, `agent`, `second_agent`, `follow_up`, `funding_dt`, `amt_granted`, `cred_review_fee_amt`, `cred_review_fee_dt_paid`, `cred_estab_fee_amt`, `cred_estab_fee_dt_paid`, `liq_fee_amt`, `liq_fee_dt_paid`, `miscel_fee_amt`, `miscel_fee_dt_paid`, `df_cnslt_fee_amt`, `df_cnslt_fee_date_paid`, `cred_repair_fee_amt`, `cred_repair_fee_dt_paid`, `lead_src`, `bst_time_to_call`, `p_psn2`, ......................

Comment: I think that's about as good as you're going to get it without looking at partitioning, hardware, and configuration - all beyond my area of 'expertise' (I use that term loosely). Maybe ask in the http://dba.stackexchange.com/ forum.

Comment: As an aside, your table uses a lot of HASH indexes. But it also seems to specify an Innodb table. As far as I know MySQL Innodb tables do not support HASH type indexes.

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam - `*` versus spelling them out: no difference.  `*` versus spelling out _only the columns you need_: could be a big difference.

Comment: @Kickstart - MySQL supports `HASH` in one situation, but not this situation.  It silently turns `HASH` into `BTree`, which is _nearly as good anyway_.

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam - Oh, "3rd party".  I have choice words to say about how they often "get in the way of effective use of MySQL, rather than facilitating the use".  Sounds like their model is to fetch everything into RAM and work there.  Ugh.

Comment: It is almost never wise to create a table with that many columns or that many indexes.  If you are being forced to use this 3rd party software, I recommend that you warm up your resume.

Comment: Yep, quite hideous having that many columns on a table.