# How to improve query performance with auto increment field as primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I'm using following query of third party application that seems to be taking too time for executing in PHP. [Table Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482054/speed-up-mysql-table-query)

```
SELECT auto_id, customer_id, apply_dt, priority_opt, cust_apl_by, cust_upd_by, cust_upd_dt, agent, second_agent, follow_up, funding_dt, amt_granted, cred_review_fee_amt, cred_review_fee_dt_paid, cred_estab_fee_amt, cred_estab_fee_dt_paid, liq_fee_amt, liq_fee_dt_paid, miscel_fee_amt, miscel_fee_dt_paid, df_cnslt_fee_amt, df_cnslt_fee_date_paid, cred_repair_fee_amt, cred_repair_fee_dt_paid, lead_src, bst_time_to_call, p_psn2, p_fl_nm, p_ph1, p_ph2, p_eml1, p_eml2, p_amt_req, p_cmt, p_fr_nm, p_mi_nm, p_la_nm, p_hm_ph, p_hm_addr, p_ye_addr, p_city, p_state, p_zip, p_dob, p_ss, p_is_us, p_mam_maiden_nm, p_drv_lic, p_unq_id, p_hv_af, p_wh_af, p_hv_dod, p_wh_dod, p_bnk_nm, b_stg, b_leg_nm, b_ent_typ, b_ind_typ, b_fed_tax_id, b_ph, b_fax, b_addr, b_city, b_state, b_zip, b_ye_busi, b_empl, b_reg_state, b_wb_site, b_bnk_nm, b_acpt_cred_card, b_hv_cred_card, b_seeking, b_hv_not_show_cred_card, b_wht_bnk_issu_thm, b_hv_401k_ira, b_how_much, b_cred_premis, b_cred_usr, b_cred_pwd, p2_ph1, p2_ph2, p2_eml, manager, p2_relation, p2_dob, p2_ss, p2_cred_usr, p2_cred_pwd, b_new_buss, p2_hm_addr, p2_city, p2_state, remarks, p_psn3, p3_ph1, p3_ph2, p3_relation, p3_dob, p3_ss, p3_eml, p3_cred_usr, p3_cred_pwd, p3_hm_addr, p3_city, p3_state, p1_cred_usr, p1_cred_pwd, b_facs_no, b_eml, b_acc, b_acc_ph, b_own_lease, b_type, b_addition_addr, b_landlord, b_landlord_ph, b_landlord_fr, b_landlord_to, b_landlord_month_pmt, b_landlord_renew_opt, b_landlord_renew_ye, b_landlord_payment, b_landlord_approx, b_cash, b_amex, b_vs_mc, b_other, b_is_season, b_month_season_begin, b_month_season_to, is_opportunity_yes, p2_zip, p3_zip, drip, last_action_day, drip_start_dt, language, opt_yes_no, opportunity, sms_log_agent, call_log_agent, mail_log_agent, quali_guide_result, quali2_guide_result, p2_quali_guide_result, p2_quali2_guide_result, p3_quali_guide_result, p3_quali2_guide_result, quali_result, rev_total_bal, rev_total_limit, rev_total_ups, rev_total_downs, rev_fund_needed, p2_rev_total_bal, p2_rev_total_limit, p2_rev_total_ups, p2_rev_total_downs, p2_rev_fund_needed, p3_rev_total_bal, p3_rev_total_limit, p3_rev_total_ups, p3_rev_total_downs, p3_rev_fund_needed, keepaneye, p_agency, p2_agency, p3_agency, vendor_priority_opt, cur_credit_report1, cur_credit_report2, cur_credit_report3, quali_range, quali_cond, quali_name, quali_state, p2_quali_range, p2_quali_cond, p2_quali_name, p2_quali_state, p3_quali_range, p3_quali_cond, p3_quali_name, p3_quali_state, quali_range_value, p2_quali_range_value, p3_quali_range_value, max_quali_range_value, max_quali_cond, max_quali_range 
FROM customer_info 
USE INDEX (customer_id) where customer_id='xxxxx'
```

Explain result:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  customer_info   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1025952
```

This table is being used many times in PHP file.

Comment: The query fetches whole table. There is no benefits of using index. There nothing to improve in the query itself, yet application logic may need some optimisation.

Comment: How long does the query take to complete? I agree with Alex, there's a fair amount of data in the table (1.02m rows), it's bound to take some time. The `USE INDEX` index hint makes no sense on a query that makes no use of the index in the `WHERE` condition. Your query has no `WHERE` condition and therefore won't use any index.

Comment: Adding the `WHERE` clause (which you did in an edit) _totally_ changes the question and any answer.  Which do you want to discuss??

Comment: the `where` clause didn't change question but answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple select without WHERE clause and without much data shouldn't be that much long to respond. Connectivity issues?

If the third party is taking long time to respond without connectivity issues, you won't be able to do anything on their side.

Just cache the returned data and refresh it once every x time independently of what you're currently doing. And work only on your cached data. If the data is a `DataSet` from MySQL, you can use `SqlChangeMonitor` ([an example here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167282/NET-MemoryCache-with-SqlChangeMonitor)).

Comment: as I said its being used multiple times in php file, so I need such solution to reuse data if possible

Comment: a cache is exactly a reuse data only assuming it doesn't change that fast and even if it does SqlChangeMonitor should be able to handle it

Comment: Fetching the entire table is being used multiple times?  Then _abandon that 3rd party software_!

Comment: @RickJames I agree with you. Sounds like an awful 3rd party.

Answer (score 3):

Your posted query has no `WHERE` or filter condition and as can be seen from explain result that it's not using any index. Include some filter condition (`where` condition on any indexed column) and see the query plan again

Comment: the `USE INDEX (customer_id)` is already there and when I use it in `where` clause it show same

Comment: "show same" -- same what?  Surely not the same `EXPLAIN`.  There is an index that it would use, with or without the `USE INDEX`.